# Mechanism similar to SQL to filter and sort objects

Tags: java, sql

Firstly,let me say, that the example I show here is very simple and very far from the real situation. However this example shows the core of the problem well enough.

I have a class Person

```
public class Person{
private int Id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private Date birthDate;
private int age;
//+ getters and setters
}
```

And I have for example list of 2000 java(!) objects of this class. I mean I have 2000 persons. Now I need to filter and sort them using sql query. For example I would like to get the persons from these 2000 `WHERE birthDate BETWEEN 1920-04-05 AND 2000-08-10 ORDER BY lastName,firstName`.

I understand that sql language is part of sql database.s So I could save my objects to mem database,for example H2, after that do select with the necessary `WHERE` and `ORDER` clauses. However, the problem is that I this case lose performance as I already have these objects. What I need is just to get the list of the ID of these objects and that's all as I get the interval and order.

So my question - are there any solutions (libs etc) to make filtering and sorting on java objects including all common types? Maybe there are some,that even support sql language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it with **[JoSQL](http://josql.sourceforge.net/manual/introduction.html)**:

> **JoSQL** (*SQL for Java Objects*) provides the ability for a developer to apply a SQL statement to a collection of Java Objects. JoSQL provides the ability to search, order and group ANY Java objects and should be applied when you want to perform SQL-like queries on a collection of Java Objects.

This is the query you need:

```
SELECT id
FROM   package.Person
WHERE  toDate (birthDate) BETWEEN toDate ('1920-04-05') 
AND    toDate ('2000-08-10')
```

And this is how to use it:

```
Query q=new Query();
q.parse("SELECT id FROM   package.Person WHERE  toDate (birthDate) BETWEEN toDate ('1920-04-05') AND  toDate ('2000-08-10')");
List<?> results=q.execute(names).getResults();
```

**EDIT:**

This is how you will fetch this results:

```
List<?> results=q.execute(names).getResults();
Iterator<List> it = results.iterate();
while(it.hasNext()){
    List ls = it.next();
    System.out.println("Id: "+ls.get(0));
}
```

Because you will get a **List** of **Lists** as a result, where each List will contain an `id` value.

You can follow this **[JoSQL tutorial](http://www.javatips.net/blog/2014/04/josql-tutorial)**.

Comment: What is the difference `SELECT * FROM...` between `SELECT id FROM`.

Comment: `SELECT *` will select all the properties of `Person` while `SELECT id` will select only the id.

Comment: To tell the truth I don't understand because josql returns THE SAME OBJECTS we give to it.

Comment: What do you mean by THE SAME OBJECTS?

Comment: When you call `q.execute(names)` names is a collection of Objects. JoSql as I understood doesn't create new objects if I just use filtering and sorting. JoSQL returns you the same objects that were in list but applying filtering and sorting rules.

Comment: You didn't understand me at all.

Comment: @JimJim2000 Yes you are right about it, take a look at the EDIT in my answer, it's all explained.

Comment: Thank you. I think then the difference is that `*` returns the same objects and `id` will return the ids of that objects.

Answer (score 3):

http://josql.sourceforge.net/ looks like a possibility to do exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use Java 8 Stream API?

```
 List<Integer> ids = listOfPerson.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getBirthDate().isAfter(from) && person.getBirthDate().isBefore(to))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getLastName).thenComparing(Person::getFirstName))
            .map(Person::getId)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I believe JoSQL or other libraries like it are using reflection behind, so it won't be very performant. And what happens when you change name of a field?
Also, in Stream API you can use parallel processing as easy as `listOfPerson.parallelStream()`

For more info: [Use stream operations to express sophisticated data processing queries](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/ma14-java-se-8-streams-2177646.html)