# Java sort with independent reversed

Tags: java, sql, sorting

I have the issue with Java sort. In SQL, I can sort independently on each field. I need something similar in Java.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Stuff ORDER BY name ASC,last_name DSC;
```

When using `sort(Comparator.comparing(Stuff::getName).thenComparing(Stuff::getLastName).reversed()` I get the whole sort reversed, and I want only for the second sort to be in reversed order. Is there a library for it, or a simple way to solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an overload of `thenComparing()` which takes a `Comparator` so you can compose them as wanted. Actually, `thenComparing(function)` is just a convenience method for `thenComparing(comparing(function))`

Thus you can use this:

```
Comparator.comparing(Stuff::getName)
          .thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Stuff::getLastName).reversed())
```

Which is equal to

```
Comparator<Stuff> nameAscComparator = Comparator.comparing(Stuff::getName);
Comparator<Stuff> lastNameDescComparator = Comparator.comparing(Stuff::getLastName).reversed();

Comparator<Stuff> combined = nameAscComparator.thenComparing(lastNameDescComparator);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I was checking that answer, but gradle could not find some classes which should be in that library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31583096/mechanism-similar-to-sql-to-filter-and-sort-objects

Answer (score 0):

I always have the same problem. So I defined three helper methods (`orderBy`, `asc` and `desc`) to simply describe comparators.

```
@SafeVarargs
public static <T> Comparator<T> orderBy(Comparator<T> first, Comparator<? super T>... rest) {
    for (Comparator<? super T> e : rest)
        first = first.thenComparing(e);
    return first;
}

public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> asc(Function<? super T, ? extends U> f) {
    return Comparator.comparing(f);
}

public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T> desc(Function<? super T, ? extends U> f) {
    return Collections.reverseOrder(Comparator.comparing(f));
}
```

Here's an example usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Stuff> list = Arrays.asList(
        new Stuff("A", "a"),
        new Stuff("B", "b"),
        new Stuff("A", "c"));
    list.sort(orderBy(asc(Stuff::getName), desc(Stuff::getLastName)));
    list.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

output:

```
Stuff [name=A, lastName=c]
Stuff [name=A, lastName=a]
Stuff [name=B, lastName=b]
```

If you want to sort by a single property, you can also do something like `list.sort(desc(Stuff::getLastName))` without `orderBy()`.